# How to create a plotly bar and line chart combined?

Tags: python, plotly

I am using

```
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y='var1')
fig.show()
```

But I want to add

```
fig = px.bar(df, x='date', y='var2')
fig.show()
```

[image]

How would I achieve the output illustrated on the img?

Comment: You may find the examples in this [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/graphing-multiple-chart-types/#multiple-trace-types-with-plotly-express) helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to plot a bar & line chart combined with a bar chart as subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292750/plotly-how-to-plot-a-bar-line-chart-combined-with-a-bar-chart-as-subplots)

Comment: [Plotly: Add line to bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62843197/7758804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `fig.add_trace` in this case.Please refer below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2022-01-07','2022-02-07','2022-03-07','2022-04-07','2022-05-07','2022-06-07','2022-07-07','2022-08-07'],
    'var1': [5,7,2,4,6,8,10,9],
    'var2': [6,7,8,5,2,6,3,1],
    'var3':[8,5,6,2,8,3,5,4],
    'var4':[7,9,7,5,3,4,2,1]})

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['date'],y=df['var1']))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'],y=df['var2'],mode='lines'))
fig.show()
```

And here is the Output:
[image]